# How to rename the dynamic outputs using command center

Tags: command, rename, center, hp-exstream

I am generating the multiple PDF outputs using command center and i want to rename the each outputs dynamically i.e. I want to keep prefix & suffix as is of output file name and middle word(Which will be one of the customer data unique number) need to renamed with using command center file management phase.

Example: From "ABC_12345678_27jul18.pdf" to "ABC_87654321_27jul18.pdf"

Kindly suggest.Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done with Command Center but you can create a variable to use for file naming withing the exstream application itself and set the output breaks to break on every customer.  Just don't include a folder name in it as it will create the output in the job folder.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't direct option in Command Center to dynamically name outputs. As Mike mentioned, you should use file naming variable if you know what value should be the substring in your final output name and let it calculate after output break.

If the value isn't known to you during the run-time, I recommend to initiate an external script phase in Command Center and update filename once you have data available.